# Instead of a rewrite, just load old ASP pages from new ASP.NET MVC site. Is this dirty?

Tags: asp.net, architecture, asp-classic

Creating a new version of a classic asp (vbscript) site in ASP.NET MVC. Users will have the option to use either the new site or the old one. Both will run side by side.

Old legacy vbscript classic ASP site has no separation between logic and UI, thus making it impossible to rewrite properly. Tens-of-thousands of lines of Response.Write's and nearly every inline sql call consists of at LEAST an update/insert/delete/select... all within the same string.

I'm in a time crunch. Instead of trying to reverse engineer this nightmare, when I need certain functionality in the new MVC site, I simply make a call to the corresponding old classic asp page via jQuery or the Html Agility Pack. I'm trying to consolidate the number of steps in a process within the MVC site, so /StepA (MVC) would call /step1.asp, /step2.asp, and step3.asp of the classic site.

It works, but it makes me feel dirty... like a two dollar hooker. Has anyone else done something similar?

Comment: I'm all for doing this in a time crunch. But you gain a _insane_ technical debt with this. If I had to come on a maintenance job on a site build like this I would cry inside :(.

Comment: Oh, don't get me wrong, I cry with every line of dirty code I write.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your old code and how it makes easy. would wish to create it  the site from scratch if time permits because that would helpful in future changes

Comment: Unfortunately time doesn't permit. What would you do?

Answer (score 0):

Bite the bullet and rewrite. This is going to be a performance and maintenance nightmare that will likely end up being more expensive than a pre-emptive rewrite. If this is a 1:1 sort of rewrite, cheap offshoring could be a great option, given the template of the existing site and functionality to serve as a spec.